# PCI-Express device refuses to wake up from D3

Tags: power-management, pci, fpga

I’m working with a fpga expansion card (pci-e connected; terasic de10 pro).

My problem is whenever I don’t use the card for a couple of minutes it stops completely and only a complete shutdown can reawaken it. My driver tells me something like “device refuses to wake up from D3”. I assume the pci-e ip on the fpga has trouble handling power states(?)

Has anyone an idea how to prevent the card from sleeping?

Or has an idea why this is happening in the first place?